# How to upload a file with the same name to Amazon S3 and overwrite existing file?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

```js
s3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: file,
        ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data)
    }
);
```

I use this code to upload image to my Amazon S3 cloud storage. But I can't upload a file with the same name (this name exist on the server S3 already).

How can I upload a file with the same name and overwrite the already existing one in S3?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does the bucket have versioning enabled or some other policy as updating file should work by default

Comment: Please help us understand your problem better.  As @VsevolodGoloviznin says, uploading a file with the same path and name (S3 calls this the *object key*) should automatically replace the old file with the new.  The old file will not actally be deleted but will instead only be hidden if versioning is enabled on the bucket.

Answer (score 65):

By default, when you upload the file with same name. It will overwrite the existing file. In case you want to have the previous file available, you need to enable versioning in the bucket.

Comment: In case any one wants a reference, "Amazon S3 is a distributed system. If it receives multiple write requests for the same object simultaneously, it overwrites all but the last object written" 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: Please note that if you click 'Upload' in the S3 UI, drag-and-drop the file, and then simply click 'Upload' then it may change the file's permissions. For example, we lost the 'Public' read access, so we had to repeat the steps and add that permission.

Answer (score 18):

I guess you've encountered the default caching mechanism which is 24 hours, this results in not receiving the latest stored object.
To override this, add parameter to putObject():

`CacheControl: "no-cache"`
or `Expires: new Date()`

Comment: I had similar issue,while uploading to same s3 path. Resolved bu setting CacheControl (Y)

Comment: Great reminder for the forgetful ones :)

Comment: good, answer, but it always better to add simple example call to the method mentioned with the new argument it will be easier

Comment: Setting `CacheControl` cache control didn't work for me but setting `Expires` did the trick. Thanks!