# Why does `aws_s3_bucket_object` delete the folder and files form `s3` bucket by `TerraForm`?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I have below configuration in `terraform` to upload file to `s3` bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket = "${var.s3_bucket}"
  key    = "deploy/${var.file_name}"
  source = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_path}"

}
```

It does upload the file to the bucket specified in the configuration. But what is wrong is that each time it delete the folder and file from `s3` bucket and re-create them. So it deletes the folder `deploy` from the bucket and re-create it then upload the file to the folder. Note that the `file_name` has timestamp on it so it is not same for each run.

How can I make it only create them if they don't existing? And avoid deleting existing files.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40481278/831878) and its answers help at all, or is that something different?

Comment: It is different because the deploy file name in my case is different each time. and I believe it is caused by `terraform`

Comment: When you say "it deletes the folder" do you mean that if you had objects `deploy/a`, `deploy/b`, and `deploy/c` and you only wanted to upload a new version of `deploy/b`, then it would actually delete `deploy/a` and `deploy/c`? What do you mean by "deletes the folder"? Does it really wipe out other objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `deploy` folder is being removed along with the file as they are both managed via the same resource and terraform considers that both need to be replaced as it doesn't think it can just modify it.

You could try creating a second resources just for the folder and then using that for the object upload .e.g.:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folder" {
  bucket = "${var.s3_bucket}"
  key    = "deploy/"
  source = "/dev/null"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket = "${var.s3_bucket}"
  key    = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.folder.key}${var.file_name}"
  source = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_path}"

}
```